# SSRS minimal permission to download reports

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, ssrs, ssrs-2012

I received this request from a developer:

> When I try to download *.rdl report files from myssrs_server/Reports
>   I’m getting this error:

[image]

> Would you be able to extend my permissions so I can download reports
>   from all branches?

What is the minimal permission I should grant in order for him to get this done?

Any alternatives? (I was thinking about granting read only access to the reportServer database or something on those lines - but I don't want to make their lives too difficult )

I found this article very good regarding ssrs permissions:

[SQL Server Reporting Services 2012 Permissions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2793/sql-server-reporting-services-2012-permissions/)

Webpage were all the ssrs [Predefined Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157363.aspx) are explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, just so that I don't need to download the reports for them to edit, I have granted a very selective AD group with the contents manager permission, so that they can do their work.

any better alternative please post an answer or comment, I will review the situation accordingly.

[image]